# Multisite on Windows with wildcard subdomains

Tags: multisite, subdomains, windows

I want to create a local network on a Windows machine using subdomains. I do not want to edit the `hosts` file for each new subdomain. But Windows does not support wildcard subdomains, and the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Wildcard_Subdomains) doesn’t say anything useful about this topic.

What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a plugin for that: [WP XAMPP Multisite Subdomains](http://www.code-styling.de/deutsch/entwicklungen/wordpress-plugin-wp-xampp-multisite-subdomains). Unfortunately, there is no English description available. I’ll try that here.
The following guide will set up a multi-site under `mu.wp` with subdomains.

### 1. Basic Installation

Start with a fresh installation of WordPress and [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). [Create a network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) for subdomains. Do not create any sub site yet.

My XAMPP is installed in `E:\xampp`, WordPress in `E:\wordpress.latest.final`, and my site specific directories in `F:\sites`. There is a directory `F:\sites\_logs` for log files.
Make sure to adjust the paths in the following examples to your set up.

### 2. The `hosts` file

Open the `hosts` file. On Win 7 that’s probably on `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, and you need administrator rights to edit it.

Create a separate section like this:

```
# BEGIN XAMPP-127.0.0.2
127.0.0.2           mu.wp
# END XAMPP-127.0.0.2
```

Note we use `127.0.0.2`, not `127.0.0.1`. This is important.

Save the file, close and forget.

### 3. The `httpd-vhosts.conf`

Open the Apache vhosts file in `/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`.

Create a new virtual host. If that is your first virtual host you need a generic vhost first.

#### generic vhost

Should be the first virtual host in the file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "E:/xampp/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Options +Includes
        AllowOverride FileInfo
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.shtml index.html index.htm
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog  "F:\sites\_logs\default.error.log"
    CustomLog "F:\sites\_logs\default.access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

#### our multi-site vhost

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
    ServerName      mu.wp
    DocumentRoot    "E:\wordpress.latest.final"
    <Directory "E:\wordpress.latest.final">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog        "F:\sites\_logs\mu.wp.error.log"
    CustomLog       "F:\sites\_logs\mu.wp.access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure all the paths are correct! Restart Apache.

### 4. Install the plugin

Install the plugin *WP XAMPP Multisite Subdomains* as a [MU-plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins). Usually in `wp-content/mu-plugins`.

Done.

You can create new subdomains now in `http://mu.wp/wp-admin/network/site-new.php`, the plugin will update the `hosts` file automatically, and your new sites are available immediately.