# subdomain mulitsite on localhost in a subfolder

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping, local-installation

I have a sudomain-based WPMU installation locally with xampp. My `vhosts` lists domains like follows:

```
127.0.0.1 mainDomain.com
127.0.0.1 siteA.mainDomain.com
127.0.0.1 siteB.mainDomain.com
127.0.0.1 siteA.com
127.0.0.1 siteB.com
```

The `WordPress MU Domain Mapping` PlugIn maps "real-domains" on system-subdomains.

To have a standard project structure, I would like to move my installation from the documentRoot to a subfolder.

My question is, what do I need to do, to accomplish that and will it have any consequences for the compatibility between my local- and a live-system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multisite cannot be installed in a subdirectory of the document root currently. This will be possible in 3.5.

See [Multisite on Windows with wildcard subdomains](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69742/multisite-on-windows-with-wildcard-subdomains) for a guide how to manage subdomains automatically on Windows with XAMPP. You can [move the plugin directory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15483/symbolic-links-on-dev-box-with-plugins-and-stylesheets/15484#15484) to another directory per `wp-config.php`. This is possible for themes too, but automatic theme upgrades [will fail](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22501) currently.

Comment: Thx for your help. Simple question: I am fine adding `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/maindomain/"` to my apache httpd.conf, which will keep my htdocs clean. This won't have any implications on the system, right?

Comment: I wouldn’t put website files into the XAMPP directory. Makes upgrades and backups too difficult. Keep software and data separately. I am running XAMPP in `E:\xampp`, and WordPress in `E:\wordpress.latest.final`. Uploads are in `F:\sites\uploads.wp\mu`, plugins and themes in `F:\Dropbox\wp-content`. `F:\` is for data, `E:\` for software.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of an extra resource, how to set this up the right way?

Comment: No, sorry. I should write this up some day.

Comment: Np, ..but looking forward to it :)
However, thanks for your hints!